# Registering PowerApps Runtime Service API within Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, powerapps

I was attempting to register PowerApps Runtime Service during 'New App. Registration" within Azure AD.

It was not provided as a option on "Select an API" blade so I added to the manifest file as indicated within the [Trouble Shooting section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/common-data-service/entity-reference/cds-sdk-azure-functions-get-started) "Required permissions service isn't found" above.

Saved manifest, now when I navigate to "*Required permissions*" blade,  I'm presented with the GUID "82f77645-8a66-4745-bcdf-9706824f9ad0" and when selected -  I get the following message : "**The service principal for this application object has been removed from the directory or is not available."**

I'm a little unsure how to resolve this error ? Any pointers would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To use the **Common Data Service** you need to follow the Prerequisites:

> 1.If you've already signed up for PowerApps, go to PowerApps, and sign in. If you've signed up yet, follow these instructions to sign up.
>   Make sure that you have admin access to an environment that contains a Common Data
>
> 2.Service database. Go to the PowerApps portal, click the gear symbol in the upper right of the page, and then click Admin center. If you don't have admin access to any environments that contain a database, follow these instructions to create a database.

After that you it should show the required permissions like below:
[image]

Comment: just worked out the issue-- not sure of the solution. I have two directories within Azure (MSDN and o365). One has my subscriptions associated with it and code that wants to use CDS and the other o365 Azure AD appears to allow me to register CDS. I'm a little confused - any pointers

Comment: Based on my understanding, you should use the directory which associate the PowerApps. If want to test using the tenant which is not available for the PowerApps, you can signed up for PowerApps, after that it should also work for you.